# Changing Position of Cursor Between 2 Text Inputs in HTML Form

Tags: html, forms, input, caret

I have a simple search form with 2 text input fields. Here is the code;

```
<div id="mini-search-wrapper">
  <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
     <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required/>
     <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="artist"/>
     <input type="submit" class="s-submit" value="Şarkıcı Ara"/>
  </form>
  <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
      <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required />
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="lyrics" />
      <input type="submit" class="s-submit pos-center" value="Şarkı Ara"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

It looks like that;

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSeQb.jpg)

My problem is;

Position of the cursor starts from second input box when you open this form. I want to change the cursor (caret) position such that when a user click this form, position of the cursor will be in first input box, not second.

How can I choose starting position of cursor when you have many inpux text boxes in a HTML form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus onload:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("s").focus(); // remember IDs must be unique
}
```

Alternative if you have fields of same name:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByName("s")[0].focus(); // focus first of this name
}
```

---

But why two forms?

```
  <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
     <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required/>
     <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="artist"/>
     <input type="submit" class="s-submit" value="Şarkıcı Ara" 
      onclick="this.form.post_type.value='artist'"/>
     <input type="submit" class="s-submit pos-center" value="Şarkı Ara" 
      onclick="this.form.post_type.value='lyrics'"/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add autofocus attribute to input, like this:

```
    <div id="mini-search-wrapper">
  <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
     <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required/>
     <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="artist"/>
     <input type="submit" class="s-submit" value="Şarkıcı Ara"/>
  </form>
  <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
      <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required autofocus="true"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="lyrics" />
      <input type="submit" class="s-submit pos-center" value="Şarkı Ara"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your input an unique ID and set the focus onLoad with [JQuery's .focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Like

```
<div id="mini-search-wrapper">
    <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
        <input type="search" id="s" name="s" class="s-input" required/>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="artist"/>
        <input type="submit" class="s-submit" value="Şarkıcı Ara"/>
    </form>
    <form role="search" action="/" method="get">
        <input type="search" id="s2" name="s" class="s-input" required autofocus="true"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="lyrics" />
        <input type="submit" class="s-submit pos-center" value="Şarkı Ara"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('#s').focus();
});
```

Comment: OP did not tag jQuery.

Comment: @mplungjan agreed, then this is just an option if someone does.

Comment: Also your code does not focus onload but on click of any input field - and the ID is not unique